# Загрузка нескольких изображений к посту в Django

Tags: django

Я пытаюсь сделать на сайте загрузку нескольких изображений к одной публикации через форму. Находил несколько решений на просторах интернета, но моих познаний не хватает, чтобы довести все это до рабочего варианта. При заполнении формы на сайте и нажатии кнопки создать, форма перезагружается, вписанные поля остаются заполненными, а в поле файл пишется что файл не выбран. Первый раз на этом сайте, если что не так написал, прошу не ругать.

Вот моя модель(model):

```py
class Car(models.Model):

    car_title = models.CharField('Заголовок объявления', max_length=100, blank=True, db_index=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.IntegerField('Цена', blank=True, null= True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField('Телефон', max_length=30, blank=True)
    car_description = models.TextField('Описание', blank=True)
    avito_item = models.CharField('Авито номер', max_length=100, blank=True)
    car_brand = models.CharField('Марка авто', max_length=100, blank=True, db_index=True)
    car_model = models.CharField('Модель авто', max_length=100, blank=True, db_index=True)
    car_generation = models.CharField('Поколение', max_length=100, blank=True)
    modif = models.CharField('Модификация', max_length=100, blank=True)
    year_of_manufacture = models.IntegerField('Год производства', null=True, db_index=True)
    car_mileage = models.IntegerField('Пробег', blank=True, null=True)
    condition = models.CharField('Состояние', max_length=100, blank=True)
    owners = models.IntegerField('Количество владельцев', blank=True, null=True)
    vin_number = models.CharField('VIN номер', max_length=100, blank=True)
    type_chassis = models.CharField('Кузов', max_length=100, blank=True)
    doors = models.IntegerField('Количество дверей', blank=True, null=True)
    engine_type = models.CharField('Тип двигателя', max_length=100, blank=True)
    transmission = models.CharField('Трансмиссия', max_length=100, blank=True)
    drive = models.CharField('Привод', max_length=100, blank=True)
    steering_side = models.CharField('Руль', max_length=100, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField('Цвет', max_length=100, blank=True)
    equipment = models.CharField('Дополнительное оборудование', max_length=200, blank=True)
    view_place = models.CharField('Место осмотра', max_length=100, blank=True)
    engine_volume = models.FloatField('Объем двигателя', blank=True, null= True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Автомобили"
        verbose_name_plural = "Автомобили"
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('car_detail_url', kwargs={'id':self.id})

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('car_update_url', kwargs={'id':self.id})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('car_delete_url', kwargs={'id':self.id})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_title

class Photo(models.Model):

    image_data_link = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d')
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='all_images')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Фотография"
        verbose_name_plural = "Фотографии"

    def get_remote_url(self):
        if self.image_url and not self.image_data_link:
            image_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
            image_temp.write(requests.get(self.image_url).content)
            image_temp.flush()
            self.image_data_link.save(f'photo_{self.pk}.jpg', File(image_temp))
        self.save()
```

Это форма(forms):

```py
class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    all_images = forms.ImageField(label=u'Фотографии', widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': 'multiple'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Car

        exclude = ['seller']
        fields = ['car_title', 'price', 'phone', 'car_description', 'avito_item', 'car_brand',
        'car_model', 'car_generation', 'modif', 'year_of_manufacture', 'car_mileage', 'condition', 'owners',
        'vin_number', 'type_chassis', 'doors', 'engine_type', 'transmission', 'drive', 'steering_side', 'color',
        'equipment', 'view_place', 'engine_volume']


        widgets = {
            'car_title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'price':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'phone':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'car_description':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'avito_item':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'car_brand':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'car_model':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'car_generation':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'modif':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'year_of_manufacture':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'car_mileage':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'condition':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'owners':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'vin_number':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'type_chassis':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'doors':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'engine_type':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'transmission':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'drive':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'steering_side':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'color':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'equipment':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'view_place':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'engine_volume':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})

                    }
```

Это вьюха(views), у меня она вынесена в файл utils (модель_форм и темплейт загружается из вьюхи):

```py
class ObjectCreateMixin:
    model_form = None 
    template = None

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.model_form()
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = self.model_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_obj = bound_form.save(commit=False)
            new_obj.seller = request.user
            new_obj = bound_form.save()
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('all_images'):
                data = f.read() #Если файл целиком умещается в памяти
                photo = Photo(car=new_obj)
                photo.image_data_link.save(f.name, ContentFile(data))
                photo.save()
            return redirect(new_obj)
        return render(request, self.template, context={'form': bound_form})
```

Это шаблон html

```py
{% extends 'bulletin_board/base_main.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Create car - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form class="" action="{{ car.car_create_url }}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {% if field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ field.errors }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                {{ field.label }}
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create car</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Вам нужно использовать formset для CarForm, это будет в джанго-стиле.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можно ли сделать это в вышеуказанном формате? Получается что есть рабочий вариант на SO, но я просто не понимаю какие нужно вставить переменные в нужные места.

Comment: Я выше неверно написал. Нужно использовать formset для modelForm модели Photo.

Comment: чтобы понять, в чем у вас проблема, надо видеть ещё код шаблона

Comment: Добавил шаблон добавления поста

Comment: Классическая ошибка. У вас не указан enctype тегу form

Comment: @Александр, спасибо огромное! В код файлов я смотрел, а вот в html не догадался даже! Помогло! Как поставить вам плюсик?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На стороне django у вас сделано все более менее грамотно, но для отправки файлов на сервер необходимо так же указать способ кодирования данных `multipart/form-data`. Он гарантирует, что сервер получит тело запроса в неизменном виде.

В настоящее время существует два способа задания способа кодирования:

- через атрибут `enctype` тега `form`
- через атрибут `formenctype` кнопки отправки формы (`input type=submit/image` или `button`)

Так же особым случаем является класс `FormData`, если отправляете изображение ajax-ом, он может проставлять способ кодирования независимо от наличия вышеперечисленных атрибутов

Так что если кратко, то решение для этого конкретного случая будет выглядеть так:

```
<form class="" action="{{ car.car_create_url }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```